# Higher education knowledge and high school knowledge and pleasure

Tags: knowledge, psychology, pain-and-pleasure, knowledge-representation, cognitive-psychology

This post wonders about the levels of pleasure that can be attained using high school only knowledge as compared to using higher education knowledge (assuming all pleasurable activities are related to knowledge).

This post may be better suited to the psychology stack exchange. If so, then please migrate my post there.

My question is a bit of a socioeconomic question, so I don't know if it is better suited to the economics stack exchange.

I don't know where to ask this is the truth.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I feel like a Jeopardy host here, but please phrase your post in the form of a question.